# PHP explode() not work with " - " character

Tags: php, explode

I want to substring the text, ex. "Hello - How are you?" by using this code

```
$text= "Hello - How are you?";
$strings = explode(' - ',$text);
echo $strings[0]; // Hello
echo $strings[1]; // How are you
```

it will not work, because of ' - '.

If i change to:

```
$text= "Hello-How are you?";
$strings = explode('-',$text);
echo $strings[0]; // Hello
echo $strings[1]; // How are you
```

it's ok.

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: That should work, are you sure they are real spaces, and not something else (e.g. an em space, en space or something?)

Comment: Check that those spaces are actually spaces and not en or em spaces: http://3v4l.org/T5P5X

Comment: Also check, that the hyphen "-" is the same ... not only the spaces.

Comment: You could always use [**`trim`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on the result to remove spaces from the begin and end of the string and simple explode on the **`-`** alone **`$strings = explode('-',$text);`**. `echo trim($strings[0]);`

Comment: Where do you get $text from? Your code, as stated by these comments, works for "normal" spaces and hypens.

Comment: it's work, check here http://ideone.com/RGFJ23

Comment: @EmilioGort not if that was a tab

Answer (score 7):

I find out another way:

```
$title= filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$title= str_replace('&#8211;', '-', $title);
$size = explode('-', $title);
```

Anything else works for me

Comment: This is the best solution and the only one that actually worked for me.

Comment: In my case, i was using double quotes like "-" and this fixed it... thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, after an hour of investigating, turns out that texts copied from Microsoft Word have such a problem, word chooses to convert the minus character ( - ) to en dash ( – ) here you can see them side by side to see the difference:
-–

I don't know why word does that, but we are used to see such annoying things done by word and you should never let anyone copy a text from word to you application!

To make you code work in these conditions you must first replace these odd characters:

```
$text= "Hello-How are you?";
$strings = str_replace('–', '-', $text);
$strings = explode('-',$text);
echo $strings[0]; // Hello
echo $strings[1]; // How are you
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, your "spaces" are not real spaces but rather tabs or similar, and the hypen could be one different from the standard one, for example `—` or `–` instead of `-`.

You could then try the following:

```
$strings = preg_split('/\s[—–-]\s/', $text);
```

to properly split that string.