# Explode not working properly with dash

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, explode

We have this string : "*Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie – 1° PARTE*" and we want to get two part of it:

1. **Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie**
2. **1° PARTE**

We are not able to get them using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on **–** char

We have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688287/php-explode-not-work-with-character) but neither of each answer worked for us.

We have tried at frontend with javascript but with not positive results.

**How can we fix it? Could it be an issue of charsted?** (currently ISO-859-1 and we cannot change it)

Comment: Is the JavaScript tag needed for this?

Comment: It would not be the first time that someone renders some HTML entity through a browser (e.g. `&mdash;`) and then try to manipulate the literal character produced (e.g. `—`)...

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes. Currently, we're not able to fix this in frontend and neither in backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "atypical" dash symbol in your string, it's called ***Unicode Character 'EN DASH' (U+2013)***.
Replace it with it's *utf-8* equivalent, then, you'll able to easily split the string:

```
$str = "Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie – 1° PARTE";
$endash = html_entity_decode('&#x2013;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

$str = str_replace($endash, '-', $str);
print_r(explode("-",$str));
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie 
    [1] =>  1° PARTE
)
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: Cool! But this is not working. Why? I'd like to give you more info but i don't really know what could i say more :(

Comment: I've used your initial string and it works fine for me. Make sure that you have set this directive `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` right at the beginning of your script

Comment: We've converted le dash on database in a normal one and worked... ha!

Answer (score 1):

The character you are exploding with is not dash.

Copy and paste the character and then try.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php
$str = 'Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie – 1° PARTE';
$arr = explode('–', $str);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output I am getting:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie 
 [1] =>  1Â° PARTE
)
```

Comment: yes, that's not a dash. For frontend javascript, you may use `var str = "Il Responsabile della Sicurezza nelle gallerie – 1° PARTE"; console.log( str.split("–") );`

Comment: But it's working for me. Just tried again in browser console and it gives the split array. Try copy/pasting this code, because as mentioned, it's not a dash which is being used in the split function.

Comment: I know! It's working for me too if i work outside of the environment. I think that's all the problem is on the CHARSET.

Comment: Too late this answer but i give you a thumb up for the try

Answer (score 0):

I tried all your solutions and all of them worked partially in my query from the DB, so, I tried using all of them in a function

I hope this could help to get a better and global solution.

The function will check if the exploded worked and the vector has more than index zero. If is not there, it will try another method for checking the simbol

```
function get_separated_title($post_title) {
    $repared = str_replace('-', '-', $post_title);
    $titulo = explode("-", $repared);

    if (!isset($titulo[1])) {
        $raw = filter_var($post_title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $repared = str_replace('&#8211;', '-', $raw);
        $titulo = explode("-", $repared);
        if (!isset($titulo[1])) {
            mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
            $endash = html_entity_decode('&#x2013;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
            $repared = str_replace($endash, '-', $raw);
            $titulo = explode("-", $repared);
        }
    }
    return $titulo;
}
```